# Switch not giving correct results in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, switch-statement

I am trying simple code to test the Switch statement in PowerShell. It is not running the correct script block for the conditions that are not falling in to any of the conditions handled though Switch statements.

```
$Age = Read-Host "Age"

Switch ($Age)
{
    { (($_ -gt 0) -and ($_ -le 25)) } { Write-Host "You are too young" }
    { (($_ -gt 25) -and ($_ -le 50)) } { Write-Host "You are still young" }
    { (($_ -gt 50) -and ($_ -le 75)) } { Write-Host "You are Closer to your death" }
    { (($_ -gt 75) -and ($_ -le 99)) } { Write-Host "I am surprised you are still alive" }
    Default { "Invalid age" }
}
```

For example: if you input -12 or 110 as value for `$Age` parameter, it should run the Default block (Invalid age), but it is running the first condition.

```
Age: -12
You are too young

Age: 110
You are too young
```

However, it works perfectly for other values between 0-99.

```
Age: 12
You are too young

Age: 30
You are still young

Age: 55
You are Closer to your death

Age: 88
I am surprised you are still alive
```

Can someone please suggest what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens as Powershell is dynamically typed. The variable `$Age` can be a string or integer (or something else...), which rises the ambiguity. Like so,

```
$Age = Read-Host "Age"
Age: 110
PS C:\> $Age.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object

$Age = Read-Host "Age"
Age: 55
PS C:\> $Age.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType
```

In order to make the variable an `int`, declare it as such:

```
[int]$Age = Read-Host "Age"
Age: 110
PS C:\> $Age.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType
```

Comment: Another approach is to swap the ordering `($_ -gt 0)` -> `(0 -lt $_)`, as the implicit casting will tend to make the thing on the right match the thing on the left, so put the number on the left.

Comment: Wow!! Excellent. That works perfectly. Thank you for pointing out the data type issue. I never thought it would work that way.